# Can't link my Stack Overflow account in my Careers profile

Tags: support, jobs, linked-accounts

I cannot add the Stack Exchange network sites I'd like to display on my profile

[image]

Why?

If it's possible I would like to have only one account, please be careful, please don't erase my profile.

Comment: You should be able to add the email you used on Careers to your logins on your Stack Overflow account, and it should link them together. Also, you shouldn't post your email addresses here.

Comment: I still can add my Stach Exchange network, and i cant get my 0/10 Linked Accounts point. Please help